# How to save the order for jQuery UI portlet plugin?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the portlet plugin from jQuery UI

my question is:

is it possible to save the order of the portlets in the database so when the user come back he can see his portlets sorted in the same order?How?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://www.nabble.com/saving-portlet-state-td21951006s27240.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't really answer your question but I would suggest this:

If the order of portlets is not mission-critical, then use cookies to store the order instead of using a database. This will save you valuable space and performance.

Plus, you get to support users that have not logged in.

Comment: Thanks for the advise your solution is great for some  sort of websites I store every thing in the database since the cookies can be deleted and also if the user access his page from another computer I want hem to find his preference. and also because only logged in users can use my the system.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this the cookie saving method and my saving to the database.

The database way is really the best method

When I saved box positions with a cookie, the page would load and the boxes would be in there default position, then when the page finished reading the cookie it would re-arrange the boxes from the cookie data which made the page look really slow